# ExtJS - Get array on DOM nodes in Grid, highlight()?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, highlight

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I have a grid with entries that a user can "batch update", that is a user can select a single or multiple entries from the grid, select values from a form above the grid that they want to apply to all entries, and then submit.

What I'd like to accomplish is a highlight() done on all the changes rows. The problem I'm having is I don't know how to run a highlight() on all of the changes values at once, so I've been doing it individually. I might just be running through the loop wrong. Here's what I'm doing to update the values.

```
// for every property we have in our batchUpdateValues
for (var propertyName in batchUpdateValues) {

    // change the selected banners attributes to match
    for (var i = 0 ; i < bannersToUpdate.length ; i++)
    {
        // if they've selected "Name", we only want to append, not replace"
        var oldName = bannersToUpdate[i].get('bannerName');
        if (propertyName == 'bannerName') {
            bannersToUpdate[i].set(propertyName, oldName +  ' ' + batchUpdateValues['bannerName']);
        } else {
            bannersToUpdate[i].set(propertyName, batchUpdateValues[propertyName]);
        }

        var changedRowId = this.getStore().indexOf(updatedBanners[i]);
        var changedRow = this.getView().getRow(changedRowId);
        Ext.get(changedRow).highlight();                   

    }                               
}
```

What's happening now is if the user selects 4 "attributes" to update form the form the highlight gets run 4 times, so I'd need to put that code outside the loop. How would I grab all of the DOM attributes for each row and then run a highlight on them()?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to make sure you understand the **SelectionModel**. It's described in the documentation. I'd link you but I'm not sure which version you're using. Actually, **what version of Ext JS are you using?** The answer to this question might be different in 3.x vs. 4.x.

I'd be happy to answer in more detail but I'll need you to **clarify with an example**. Could you build a small table with some dummy data and then explain when you're talking about rows/columns in the model?